# Multiple drop down search filter angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

im working on a search engine that takes input from 3 drop down lists.
first drop down list is category, second product type, third is price.
each drop down list populates itself according to the selection of the previous dropdown, final out put is one product that matches all three selections.
i use webapi and recieve the details as a json object that contains an array of objects. heres a demo plunker using a similar structure json file:

http://plnkr.co/edit/CVyRY69Dzlf5mLOAtVJd?p=preview

i cant seem to be able to filter and output the data from the three selected drop downs any help would be very appriciated
thenx

the json

```
[{
"caregory": "Electronics",
"products": [{
    "product": "PC",
    "description": "Item4 Product Page",
    "price": 99.99
},  {
     "product": "TV",
    "description": "lorem ipsum possum",
    "price": 250.00
}]},{
"caregory": "Home Design",
"products": [{
    "product": "Paintings",
    "description": "awesome description about anything",
    "price": 200.00
}, {
    "product": "Pencils",
    "description": "we are filters",
    "price": 29.99
}, {
    "product": "Sharpies",
    "description": "loremloremlorem",
    "price": 89.00
}]}]
```

the html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="filters.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="MyController">
      <form>
        <label for="caregory">Category</label>
        <select id="caregory" data-ng-model="selectedCategory" ng-options="option as option.caregory for option in caregories |  orderBy:'caregory'">
           <option value="">None</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
        <label for="filters">Product type</label>
        <select id="filters" ng-model="selectedCategory" ng-options="option.product as option.product for option in selectedCategory.products | unique: 'product'">
          <option value="">None</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="filters">Price</label>
        <select id="filters" ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="option.price as option.price for option in selectedCategory.products | unique: 'price'">
          <option value="">None</option>
        </select>
     <br>
     <br>     
     <button ng-click="selectedCategory=true">Search</button>     
      </form>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div ng-show="selectedCategory" ng-repeat="caregory in caregories |
                filter: { caregory : selectedCategory.Category }">
        <div ng-repeat="products in selectedCategory.products | orderBy:'-price' | filter:selectedCategory:strict ">    
        <div>{{products.caregory}}</div>      
        <div>{{products.description}}</div>       
        <div>{{products.price}}</div>        
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the js:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('MyApp', ['angular.filter'])
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http',
      function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('data.json')
          .success(function(data, status, header, config) {
            $scope.caregories = data;
            $scope.selectedCategory = $scope.categories[0];
        });

        // $scope

        $scope.$watch('selectedCategory',function(newVal){
          console.log('newValue ',newVal);
            if(!newVal){
            $scope.selectedCategory = undefined;
          }
        })
      }
    ]);
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope i understdood you , here you are.

```js
var data = [{
  "caregory": "Electronics",
  "products": [{
    "product": "PC",
    "description": "Item4 Product Page",
    "price": 99.99
  }, {
    "product": "TV",
    "description": "lorem ipsum possum",
    "price": 250.00
  }]
}, {
  "caregory": "Home Design",
  "products": [{
    "product": "Paintings",
    "description": "awesome description about anything",
    "price": 200.00
  }, {
    "product": "Pencils",
    "description": "we are filters",
    "price": 29.99
  }, {
    "product": "Sharpies",
    "description": "loremloremlorem",
    "price": 89.00
  }]
}];

var app = angular.module('app', ['angular.filter']);

var Controller = function() {

  this.selected = {};
  this.data = data;
  
  var self = this;
  this.search = function(predicate)
  {
    self.searchPredicate = predicate;
  }
}

app.controller('ctrl', Controller);
```

```html
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.8/angular-filter.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Search engine</h1>


  </div>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="caregory">Category</label>
      <select id="caregory" data-ng-model="vm.selected.category" ng-options="option as option.caregory for option in vm.data |  orderBy:'caregory'">
        <option value="">None</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      <br />
      <label for="filters">Product type</label>
      <select id="filters" ng-model="vm.selected.type" ng-options="option as option.product for option in vm.selected.category.products | unique: 'product'">
        <option value="">None</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <label for="filters">Price</label>
      <select id="filters" ng-model="vm.selected.price" ng-options="option as option.price for option in vm.selected.category.products | unique: 'price'">
        <option value="">None</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-if="vm.selected.price">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.search(vm.selected.price)">Search</button>
    </div>
    
    <div ng-if="vm.searchPredicate">
      Searching for <b>{{vm.searchPredicate.product}}</b> in <b>{{vm.searchPredicate.description}}</b> with price <b>{{vm.searchPredicate.price | currency}}</b>
      </div>
  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: quick question my friend: whats the best way to pass this.data from an $http.get function and not a var data?